# PHP Laravel AWS S3 - Uploading image results into a white square image

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am uploading images using Laravel S3, the upload works, but when I checked the image, I get a white square image:

[image]

I am getting the image from an external website.

This is my code:

```
  $response = Storage::disk('s3')->put("/directory/image.png, "https://externalwebsite/image.png?token=123", [
            'visibility'   => FilesystemContract::VISIBILITY_PUBLIC,
            'StorageClass' => 'INTELLIGENT_TIERING',
        ]);
```

Any tips on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: have you found the solution for this issue?